# How to get the hash from signtool?

Tags: signtool, authenticode

I understand that the Microsoft signtool utility and Powershell Set-AuthenticodeSignature cmdlet generate a hash of the data to be signed and use that to compute the signature. I need to get the hash value for auditing purposes. Are there code examples or utilities that can do that? If not, is there a guide on computing that programmatically?